# calculate the derivative of a function containing factorial

Tags: derivatives, factorial, approximation-theory

I got an expression for free energy F in a book as: 
$$F(N_1) = \frac{N_1N_2}{N}W-kT(\log N!-\log N_1!-\log N_2!),\tag1\label1$$
where $N=N_1+N_2$. As what the book later introduced, the derivative of $\eqref1$ is:
$$F'(N_1)=\frac{N_1-N_2}{N}W-kT\log\frac{N_1}{N_2}.\tag2\label2$$

Can anyone tell me the steps needed to derive $\eqref2$ from $\eqref1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation):
$$\ln n!=n\ln n-n$$

Then 
$$F(N_1) = \frac{N_1N_2}{N}W-kT(\log N!-\log N_1!-\log N_2!)$$
becomes
$$F(N_1) = \frac{N_1N_2}{N}W-kT(N\log N-N-N_1\log N_1+N_1-N_2\log N_2+N_2)$$
$$\Rightarrow F(N_1) = \frac{N_1N_2}{N}W-kT(N\log N-N_1-N_2-N_1\log N_1+N_1-N_2\log N_2+N_2)$$
$$\Rightarrow F(N_1) = \frac{N_1N_2}{N}W-kT(N\log N-N_1\log N_1-N_2\log N_2)$$

See if this helps.